# Receive Facebook Graph API access_token after external login in .NET MVC core

Tags: .net, authentication, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to receive more information about the user after successful authentication with facebook in the

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
```

method of the Account controller.

How am I able to receive the facebook access_token, so that I can use the graph api? I think I may miss something obvious but unfortunately cannot find what I am missing..

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Set `SaveTokens` to true in options.

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookOptions
{
      AppId = "",
      AppSecret = "",
      SaveTokens = true,
      ...          
};

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

And get it:

```
HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

Keep in mind to use `GetTokenAsync` you need to add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Adem. Adding the SaveTokens = true to the Facebook options now made the access_token available in var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

Comment: But unfortunately HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token"); did not work..

Comment: I tried it with cookie authentication and it worked for me, probably you use aspnet identity. Here is  a similar github issue https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/898

Answer (score 1):

Access Token may be stored in auth properties (`OAuthOptions.SaveTokens` option enable/disable this behavior, `false` by default).

Use [AuthenticationTokenExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/TokenExtensions.cs#L49) class to get token from `AuthenticationProperties`:

```
public static string GetTokenValue(this AuthenticationProperties properties, string tokenName)
public static IEnumerable<AuthenticationToken> GetTokens(this AuthenticationProperties properties)
```

For example, if you use cookie authentication:

```
var authInfo = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
string accessToken = authInfo.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");
```

---

Notice, that before RC2 tokens were stored in claims (related [PR](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/698)), so you may find old code like next one, that doesn't work

```
var token = User.FindFirst("access_token")?.Value
```